# SAS Getting Simple Calculation Wrong

Tags: sas

I can't believe I have never had this issue before (nor can I find anyone else with the same issue) but today I have just discovered that SAS sometimes gets simple calculations wrong!?! I noticed that one of my records wasn't getting picked up in the right group based on a value being <3.6 and thought there must be something strange in my data with decimal places. But on investigation I found it was just because SAS was calculating the value wrong! For some reason that I can't fathom, it seems that SAS calculates 90 - 86.4 as 3.59999999999999!!! Simple program below to show this:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI8l2.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMlLW.png)

If I alter the calculation to 10 - 6.4 I get the correct value of 3.6000 but for some reason this one is coming out wrong. Could there be some mad setting that is wrong in my installation? I tried both SAS EG and Base SAS and both have the same issue. I feel like I'm going mad! Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your discovery is an unfortunate but expected situation related to double precision representation of numeric values.   Double precision can achieve 15 or 16 decimal places of precision. Topic has been discussed here and in many other venues.  Other languages have other representations such as BigDecimal class that can ameliorate some of the 'not exact' arithmetic situations that occur when using double precision.  Finally, try SAS `ROUND` function, it can help in many cases when plain math is itty bitty off.

Comment: Hi - in the future can you please try to remember to put code and output not as pictures, but as text? Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, the moment every programmer encounters! One of the best explanations on this phenomenon is by Tom Scott: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Comment: Thanks, that video is very interesting, good to know! Thanks for the help all, sorry about the pictures

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic, in any language, will have this same issue.  The same issue is possible to understand in human terms, assuming the human doesn't have a concept of infinite.  If you only write down 4 digits for your decimals, for example, then:

```
1 - (1/3) - (1/3) - (1/3)
```

That's zero, right?

```
1 - 0.3333 = 0.6667
0.6667 - 0.3333 = 0.3334
0.3334 - 0.3333 = 0.0001
```

Nope!  Computers do the same thing, but in *binary*, so they have a different (and larger) set of "problem" numbers.  1/10, for example, is not representable in binary - so adding or subtracting 0.1 is not always a "neat" operation like it is in decimal.

SAS uses 8 byte floating points, and so it gets ~15 digits of accuracy.  Assuming you're not working in a field where 15 digits of accuracy is needed, you should simply round.

```
if round(value,.01) ge 3.6 then ... ;
```

Most of the time this isn't needed, but strictly speaking you should *always* compare rounded numbers whenever using floating point numbers (as SAS does).  Integers are safe, but if you're working with 0.1 etc., use [ROUND](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p0tj6cmga7p8qln1ejh6ebevm0c9.htm) or [FUZZ](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p18pa7u3zufu9nn1ivv67uknw3i7.htm) for integers.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation, glad to know I'm not going mad!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry Cannot replicate your findings.

```
data x;
a=90-86.4;
run;
```

Gives the correct result. Are you using any formats or put function. Share the complete code.

Comment: You skipped the `format` step, so you're formatted in `best12.` - add that and it does replicate.  (And either way, please don't use answers to make comments - this would belong in a comment, if it's not actually answering the question.)  Thanks!

Comment: Complete Steps pls. Below step does not reproduce the result  
data x;  a=90-86.4;  format a;
run;

Comment: If you run the exact code that OP posted, it does reproduce.

Comment: In any event, even if you ignore the picture they posted, you can test this trivially yourself... `data test;
  x = 90-86.4;
  if x = 3.6 then put "Success";
  else put "Fail";
run;
  `  Even without understanding how the formats work.